# No applications found - Azure Blockchain workbench

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blockchain-workbench

Yesterday I created a new blockchain workbench guided by the docs on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/workbench/deploy

The main issue is when am going to the web app, since I can't see anything, it only shows: No applications found, Contact the Workbench administrator to get access to an application.

Funny thing is that I added a user to work along with me (both propietaries and admins). He can acces to the resource and create apps. Also he can see me as a member (i only see me). Another thing to add is that he created a contract, which appears to me in the workbench and lets me to take actions on any instance of the contract (permitted by the role ive been given).

How did i lose (if) my privileges/permissions if i created the workbench?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must have checked the  access level for your own id and anyone else did not delete your access or downgrade it by mistake.

The only other way is to raise a ticket to Azure tech or recreate the scenario and track it where and at what step it is failing.